# Python make cycle continue while it wait for function to execute

Tags: python, asynchronous, tkinter

I am trying to create point in tkinter cavnas. Which is created successfully. But what i want to do is to delete this point after three seconds. Which works too. But i need cycle to continue while it waits 3 seconds and i dont know how to achieve. Because now cycle lags for 3 seconds while it waits for createPoint.

```
def createPoint(self):
    ....
    point = self.canvas.create_oval(...)
    self.update()
    ....
    time.sleep(3)
    canvas.delete(point)
    self.update()

def infiniteCycle(self):
    ....
    self.createPoint() 
    ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `after()` instead of `time.sleep()`:

```py
def createPoint(self):
    ....
    point = self.canvas.create_oval(...)
    ....
    self.canvas.after(3000, self.canvas.delete, point)
```